# python manage.py collecstatic isn't copying my .css file

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I am trying to work with static files in django.

I have watched many videos and I know I feel I am doing it correctly.

Following is the `settings.py` snippet:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn')
```

I have also added this to `urls.py`:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

When I do a collectstatic it copies all those from admin folder. But it is not copying my `.css` file from static folder. Can someone tell me where am I doing it wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setting is [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs), with an S, as it's a list of directories.

```
STATICFILES_DIRs = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```